# 2D cubic Bezier curve. Point of self-intersection

Tags: geometry, parametric, cubics, bezier-curve

I have a 2D cubic Bézier curve defined by a set of control points A, B, D and C.
How can I find a point of self-intersection P (two parameter values t)?

---

[image: Example]

Comment: By solving $$\left\lbrace~\begin{aligned} x(t_1) &= x(t_2) \\ y(t_1) &= y(t_2) \end{aligned}\right.$$where$$\begin{aligned} x(t) &= (1-t)^3 A_x + 3 (1-t)^2 t B_x + 3 (1-t) t^2 C_x + t^3 D_x \\ y(t) &= (1-t)^3 A_y + 3 (1-t)^2 t B_y + 3 (1-t) t^2 C_y + t^3 D_y \\ \end{aligned}$$but the question is, do you need an algebraic answer, or just a numerical answer?  Or, you can split the curve in two parts where $x$ or $y$ is stationary (zero derivative), and then solve it as if they were two separate curves.

Comment: @None See my answer.

Answer (score 10):

I solved this problem years ago and [the relevant code](https://gitlab.com/parclytaxel/Kinross/-/blob/f3035f3da58b1287146fce2194ab33f113c138db/kinross/paths.py#L296-338) is still in my Kinross repository.

Represent the cubic Bézier curve in the power basis:
$$(x(t),y(t))=(x_3t^3+x_2t^2+x_1t+x_0,y_3t^3+y_2t^2+y_1t+y_0)$$
Let the self-intersection parameters be $\lambda$ and $\mu$, then obviously $x(\lambda)-x(\mu)=y(\lambda)-y(\mu)=0$. Expanding, then dividing by $\lambda-\mu$ (the trivial solution), gives
$$x_3(\lambda^2+\lambda\mu+\mu^2)+x_2(\lambda+\mu)=-x_1\\
y_3(\lambda^2+\lambda\mu+\mu^2)+y_2(\lambda+\mu)=-y_1$$
Now solve this linear system for $\lambda^2+\lambda\mu+\mu^2$ and $\lambda+\mu$ and obtain
$$\lambda\mu=(\lambda+\mu)^2-(\lambda^2+\lambda\mu+\mu^2)$$
Finally, by Viète's formulas, $\lambda$ and $\mu$ are the roots of $t^2-(\lambda+\mu)t+\lambda\mu$. Either may be outside $[0,1]$, indicating a self-intersection outside the curve proper, or both may be complex, indicating no self-intersection even in the extended curve.

---

My implementation of the above algorithm in Kinross first makes an affine transformation mapping $A,B,C$ to $(0,0),(0,1),(1,1)$ respectively. Because Bézier curves are equivariant under affine transformations of their control points, the parameters of self-intersection do not change. After transforming, $D$ is at $(x,y)$ and
$$\lambda+\mu=\frac{x-3}{x+y-3}$$
$$\lambda\mu=(\lambda+\mu)^2+\frac3{x+y-3}$$

Comment: would you be willing to explain how you make that affine transform? if I understand correctly, the code that does so is lines 324-329.